# Почему не работает animation и @keyframes

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Почему не работает анимация в коде ниже?

```css
.loader{
 width:75px;
 height: 75px;
 border: 10px solid white;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-top-color:blue;
 left:50%;
 top: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate(-50% -50%);
 animation: 2s spin infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin{
 from{
  transform: translate(-50% -50%) rotate(0deg);
 }
 to{
  transform: translate(-50% -50%) rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю при сравнении сможете понять почему.

```css
.loader {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: blue;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: 2s spin infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Comment: Дело было всего лишь в запятых(( Спасибо вам большое

Comment: @АлександрПогребняк, со всеми случается, мы не роботы, чтобы делать всё идеально, желаю успехов!

Answer (score 1):

Нестандартное, интересное решение автора вопроса может быть использовано для простой реализации **лоадеров CSS** без стандартного применения `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`.

- Добавляя к исходному коду  `border-bottom-color: blue;` получаем
  простой круговой лоадер:

```css
.loader {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: 2s spin infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

- Три секции лоадера

```
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  border-left-color: blue;
```

```css
.loader {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  border-left-color: blue;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: 2s spin infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

- Разноцветный лоадер

```css
.loader {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: dodgerblue;
  border-bottom-color: crimson;
  border-left-color: yellowgreen;
  border-right-color: gold;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: 2s spin infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```